# Docker daemon processes

Tags: process, docker, daemon

I have found, that `Docker daemon` runs more than in one instance. I have got PID(13399) with `service docker status`, but there are also different PIDs. I have created only one container.

[image: docker daemon processes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the list the stats are basically the same (MEM, etc.).
These processes are actually just [forks](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) from the original process.

Forking is usually used to execute another application in the environment of the parent process (in this case: docker). I don't know what docker specifically uses it for, there are many possibilities.

Some more information on the topic [forking](http://www.geekride.com/fork-forking-vs-threading-thread-linux-kernel/).