# Why docker is launching so many daemon processes?

Tags: process, docker, daemon

Why docker is launching so many daemon processes ?

It seems that Docker [forks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420700/docker-daemon-processes?rq=1) the main process into several others. For example, after a reboot, here is the output of my console when I type `$ htop` followed by F5 :

[image: many docker processes]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/331078manydockerprocesses.png))</sub>

There is already 6 children ! However, I don't have ANY running containers, just 2 stopped ones :

```
$ docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
a24f25e42c50        jupyter/datascience-notebook   "tini -- start-notebo"   44 hours ago        Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       prickly_spence
728166c38396        nginx                          "nginx -g 'daemon off"   4 days ago          Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       some-nginx
```

This is problematic since a **lot** of child-processes start to appear after some time... and each one of them is using about 40 MB of memory, so it becomes problematic when you got dozens of processes ! So my 2 questions are :

- Am I guessing right ? `docker run -d ...` will fork the parent daemon and will never kill the child ?
- Why do I still got 6 children processes after a reboot ? **How can I clean this ?**

In advance, thanks you very much for your help guys ! :)

---

#### Extra informations :

The `$ docker info`where you see that I run on **Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS** :

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.10.3
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 10
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-55-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.767 GiB
Name: *I censored this*
ID: *I censored this*
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

And the `$ docker version` :

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:54:52 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:54:52 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: can you post `docker info` and `docker version`, and are you on Linux, Mac, Windows?

Comment: Thx for the answer. I updated my question. I run on Ubuntu server 14.04

Comment: Theses are not processes but threads. (push 'h', see the help for 'H' `show the user threads`. If you then push 'H' theses "processes" will be hidden). Why is that so? [Check the source code for thread creation](https://github.com/docker/docker/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=thread).

Comment: [Here](https://blog.docker.com/2016/04/docker-containerd-integration/) for example: _to move the container supervision out of the core Docker Engine and into a separate daemon_ which mean another thread. (note that this is for a newer version of yours that was just released.)